# Files having same prefix to be moved to another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I have a files which doesn't have extension ending  A_INI, A_FIF. And I need to write a code to search this files by user entering only A, if Exist I need to copy A_INI, A_FIF to another folder.

Example folder contains A_INI, A_FIF, A_LOG by prompting user enters file name as A.

I have to check files starting with A_* and if exist i have to move it to another folder.

How can this be achieved using batch script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not tested:

```
@echo off

setlocal
set "source_dir=C:\source"
set "destination_dir=C:\dest"

set /p "mask=Enter a pattern: "

pushd "%source_dir%"
for %%# in ("%mask%_*") do (
   copy /y "%%~#" "%destination_dir%"
)
endlocal
```